# org.json.JSONObject kotlin vs java

Tags: java, android, json, kotlin, org.json

I noticed a difference between how JSONObject behaves in Kotlin Vs Java.

In Java:

```
public class Animal {
    String name;
    int age;

    public Animal(String name, int age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Animal anim = new Animal("Dog", 2);
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(new Gson().toJson(anim));
        System.out.println(obj);
    }
}
```

We need to convert to JSON string before making a JSONObject `{"name":"Dog","age":2}` out of it. Otherwise we get empty JSONObject `{}`.

In Kotlin:

```
class Animal {
    val name: String = "Dog"
    val age: Int = 1
}

data class MadExample (
    val x: String,
    val y: String
)

fun main() {
    val mad = MadExample("mad", "example")
    println(JSONObject(mad))
    val animal = Animal()
    println(JSONObject(animal))
}
```

We don't need to convert it to JSON string before making a JSONObject.

So, my question is : what is happening behind the scenes in both these cases? Why JSONObject doesn't support objects directly in Java?

Note:- In all the above examples, I used `org.json.JSONObject`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What happens if you add property getters (`String getName()`) to your Java class? Also, please make sure to specify which `JSONObject` you're using in each case.

Comment: When property getters are added, I am getting `JSONObject` directly out of object.

Comment: For both languages, the fields need to be visible in-terms of getters for JSONObject to work on, in giving the `JSONObject`. Thanks.